# How to get total CPU % and Memory% usage on Ubuntu in using .NET core application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

Even `PerformanceCounter` is supported in .NET core, but it is not supported on the Ubuntu OS, so is there any way to get the **system overall** CPU and memory usage in a .NET core application (like the task manager shows in Windows)?

Answer (score 4):

After some searching work, I did it by below codes (some codes are from the googling result). just FYI

```
  internal static class CpuMemoryMetrics4LinuxUtils
  {
    private const int DigitsInResult = 2;
    private static long totalMemoryInKb;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the system overall CPU usage percentage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The percentange value with the '%' sign. e.g. if the usage is 30.1234 %,
    /// then it will return 30.12.</returns>
    public static double GetOverallCpuUsagePercentage()
    {
      // refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465212/net-core-cpu-usage-for-machine
      var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
      var startCpuUsage = Process.GetProcesses().Sum(a => a.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds);

      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

      var endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
      var endCpuUsage = Process.GetProcesses().Sum(a => a.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds);

      var cpuUsedMs = endCpuUsage - startCpuUsage;
      var totalMsPassed = (endTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
      var cpuUsageTotal = cpuUsedMs / (Environment.ProcessorCount * totalMsPassed);

      return Math.Round(cpuUsageTotal * 100, DigitsInResult);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the system overall memory usage percentage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The percentange value with the '%' sign. e.g. if the usage is 30.1234 %,
    /// then it will return 30.12.</returns>
    public static double GetOccupiedMemoryPercentage()
    {
      var totalMemory = GetTotalMemoryInKb();
      var usedMemory = GetUsedMemoryForAllProcessesInKb();

      var percentage = (usedMemory * 100) / totalMemory;
      return Math.Round(percentage, DigitsInResult);
    }

    private static double GetUsedMemoryForAllProcessesInKb()
    {
      var totalAllocatedMemoryInBytes = Process.GetProcesses().Sum(a => a.PrivateMemorySize64);
      return totalAllocatedMemoryInBytes / 1024.0;
    }

    private static long GetTotalMemoryInKb()
    {
      // only parse the file once
      if (totalMemoryInKb > 0)
      {
        return totalMemoryInKb;
      }

      string path = "/proc/meminfo";
      if (!File.Exists(path))
      {
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"File not found: {path}");
      }

      using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
      {
        string line = string.Empty;
        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line = reader.ReadLine()))
        {
          if (line.Contains("MemTotal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {
            // e.g. MemTotal:       16370152 kB
            var parts = line.Split(':');
            var valuePart = parts[1].Trim();
            parts = valuePart.Split(' ');
            var numberString = parts[0].Trim();

            var result = long.TryParse(numberString, out totalMemoryInKb);
            return result ? totalMemoryInKb : throw new FileFormatException($"Cannot parse 'MemTotal' value from the file {path}.");
          }
        }

        throw new FileFormatException($"Cannot find the 'MemTotal' property from the file {path}.");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, the memory path is Linux-specific and so I can't use it cross-platform, but the processor path is cool.

Answer (score 2):

You have to rely on the OS specific utilities that provide CPU and memory information.
Run the command from your application and read/parse output returned.

I found an article which looks in line with what you are trying to achieve.
[Reading Windows and Linux memory metrics with .NET Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-system-memory/)